# How do I solve this error in .net?

Tags: asp.net

Error:-System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'Username'.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conn.Open();
        string insertQuery = "insert into Registration (Name,Username,Password,Email,Phone) values ('" + tname.Text + "','" + tusename.Text + "','" + tpassword.Text + "','" + temail.Text + "','" + tphonenumber.Text + "')";
        SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",tname.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usename",tusename.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",tpassword.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",temail.Text);
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone",tphonenumber.Text);


        com.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Response.Redirect("RegistrationDatasave.aspx");
        Response.Write("Registration is successful");
        conn.Close();

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Response.Write(ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: check your table in your database.

Answer (score 2):

Parameters don't work if you don't have them in the query.

Your query should look like this instead

```
using(SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    string insertQuery = "insert into Registration (Name,Username,Password,Email,Phone) values (@Name,@Usename,@Password,@Email,@Phone)";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);

    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name",tname.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usename",tusename.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password",tpassword.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",temail.Text);
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone",tphonenumber.Text);


    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Redirect("RegistrationDatasave.aspx");
    Response.Write("Registration is successful");
}
```

Also, you need to check your Registration table that it actually has a column named `Username`

Answer (score 0):

I assume your columnname is wrong.

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Usename",tusename.Text);
```

needs to be

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username",tusename.Text);
```

So with an added r